# How to decrease .pdf size without losing quality

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

### Background

I want to decrease size of the .pdf filled with images.
In `Preview` in can be dome through `Export` and set `Quartz Filter-> Reduce File Size` before saving.

[image: Preview-Export]

### Problem

The file indeed decreased from ~30MB to 0.37MB.

But the result has such poor quality that images are barely readable.

### Question

I saw an examples of using `Image Magic` to achieve that - but can it be done by **Preview** without any external software?

Comment: Related: [How can I make a PDF document smaller?](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/121106)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The problem is - the default filter used during conversion has very low conversion settings.

Thankfully, a custom filter can be added.

### Adding custom filter step by step

1. Create new directory (if you don't have it) - `/Library/Filters`
2. Add there new filter file with unique filter - f.e. `Reduce Size with good quality.qfilter`
3. The file should contain XML with new filter - you can base on the `/System/Library/Filters/Reduce File Size.qfilter` file or use my below example. Change compression setting, image size and add unique display name for your filter.

### Filter file structure/example

I marked key settings by comments.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Domains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Applications</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Printing</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>FilterData</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ColorSettings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DocumentColorSettings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CustomLHSCorrection</key>
                <array>
                    <integer>8</integer>
                    <integer>8</integer>
                    <integer>8</integer>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <key>ImageSettings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Compression Quality</key>
    <!-- ====== Set your custom quality <0,1> ======= -->
                <real>0.75</real>
                <key>ImageCompression</key>
                <string>ImageJPEGCompress</string>
                <key>ImageScaleSettings</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>ImageScaleFactor</key>
    <!-- ====== Set your scale factor <0,1> ======= -->                 
                    <real>0.75</real>
                    <key>ImageScaleInterpolate</key>
                    <true/>
    <!-- ====== Set what sizes your images can reach ======= -->                    
                    <key>ImageSizeMax</key>
                    <integer>1684</integer>
                    <key>ImageSizeMin</key>
                    <integer>1200</integer>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>FilterType</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>Name</key>
<!-- ====== Set unique display name for your filter ======= -->
    <string>Reduce Size Good Quality</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

### Result

Select your new filter when exporting file.

[image]

---

#### Helpful articles:

- https://www.macworld.com/article/1168311/software/shrink-preview-files-without-ruining-image-quality.html

Comment: I regret that I have but one upvote to give...

Comment: You can also put it in ~/Library/Filters so no sudo needed, at least on macOS 11.6. Thank you, this was so helpful.

Comment: This no longer works because even as root you still get "Operation not permitted" when trying to add or edit anything in the /System/... directory

Comment: The "smaller" file ended up 10 times bigger....

Comment: I hit the upvote button so hard that it broke. How do I alert an admin for repairs?

Comment: @DNS why? Above you see my question + my answer to that. I didn't visit this solution for a while, if something here doesn't work etc - you can point it out, so I can update the answer. Please remember that answers are snapshots in time - they can get obsolete :) this one I've wrote 5 years ago, for whatever version of macOS was back in the days

Comment: @michalczukm It’s a joke :) I’m saying that this is a great answer.

Comment: @DNS my bad :D I oversight it - I thought it was "down vote". Silly me :badpockerface: thx for that :)

Comment: This isn't working for me - the file size only decreases by half, despite toggling all the parameters. It would be helpful if you could give a tip for how to further decrease output file size!

Comment: @GregarityNow you can try to tweak parameters - those which I've marked with comments in the XML

Comment: For me ImageSizeMax 3368 and ImageSizeMin 2400 worked best. It reduced size by 2.5x times without visible quality loss. Also, it is recommended to use ~/Library/Filters folder so you don't use root account which is not necessary here.

Answer (score 105):

#### Use Apple's built-in ColorSync Utility to create a custom filter.

You can create your own Filter to reduce the image data size in the PDF, using Apple's built-in ColorSync Utility.

Click the **Filters** tab in the toolbar. Then click + at the bottom of the window, to add a new filter. The click the cogwheel or dropdown menu on the right-hand side of your filter.

[image]

Then under "**Add Image Effects Components**", choose "**Color Image Sampling**", and optionally **Image Compression**.

[image]

Note that you can't modify the existing system ones, but you can duplicate and modify them.

Then select the Filter in Preview's Export:

[image]

*(NB: For some reason "Export As PDF" doesn't show the Filters, but Export, choosing PDF as the file format, does.)*

Comment: It worked like a charm! It worth the note, the original filter can't be modified, one has to duplicate the original filter, name it, and only then you can change it.

Comment: (Rename by double-clicking name in ColorSync Utility list.) The resulting filter ends up in ~/Library/Filters (in Catalina, at least); move it to /System/Library/Filters/ if for some reason it needs to be available system-wide.

Comment: @JLundell You can't write to /System. You can stick it in /Library/Filters for all users.

Comment: Even simplier than editing a XML file ! Thanks

Comment: Thank you! This solution works also on the new Version of Catalina 10.15.3. With this version you **can't** edit or add files in the Folder System/Library/Filters, so it appears to be the **only** solution available now.

Comment: Can you clarify the first step? I started ColorSync Utility but I don't see any function for duplicating or creating a new filter.

Comment: @KenShirriff Open a New Window, if necessary, and click on the Filters Tab.

Comment: This is working for Monterey OSX 12.3 the other solution does not work for this version

Comment: Thank you @benwiggy. This worked like a charm. I need this very often and now I have created a custom filter for myself forever.

Answer (score 18):

## Easy Way

---

### ColorSync Utility

open 'color sync utility' and choose Filters and Duplicate Filter

[image]

Set resolutions and Image Compression as 'Uncompressed'

[image]

Go to `Export` menu. (NOT `Export as PDF`)

[image]

Comment: How does this add to the answers already provided?

Comment: the answer did not mention Uncompress Mode. and no screen shot

Comment: Upvoted. The screenshots might only be a minor addition, but no other answer so far mentioned how to set up filters for **uncompressed** images, which is crucial.

Answer (score 9):

You can use ImageMagick to reduce the size of a PDF by lowering its resolution.

Install with `brew install imagemagick`, then run:

```
convert -density 72 oldfile.pdf new.pdf
```

where 72 is the target DPI.

Answer (score 5):

Preview is very limited in its capabilities.

(Although [@michalczukm's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297418/251859) might well be worth a try *for simple* documents, e.g. those PDFs *with not much structure, without Bookmarks.* Also: while you may not *visually* discern any quality loss, *it is still a lossy procedure,* but with less aggressive settings then the original Quartz-filter.)

Instead of Image Magick *or* Preview I suggest to try:

- Adobe Acrobat (expensive)

or the libre/free

- [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com) with the following parameters:
  `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=Name_of_Outputfile.pdf  To_Reduce_Input.pdf`

You may play with these settings. Those given here should not perform any lossy conversions or strip away important document structures. Meaning: most of the time the savings gained might be very good, but sometimes the file size even increases.

Ghostscript is available through a number of venues for macOS. The related [muPDF](https://mupdf.com) is even available on the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mupdf/id482941798?mt=8&uo=4).

If you created the PDF yourself then it would be obviously best to losslessly reduce the images *before* including them into the document (the PDF). Adjusting the image size in terms of pixel count/resolution appropriate for the intended output medium might produce the biggest savings.

Comment: the usage of ghostscript looks great for larger and more complex scenarios. For simple documents (that was my case) filter was quick to use and good enought. PS notice that both question and first answer are mine :)

Comment: muPDF is only on the iOS App Store, not the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 5):

As per michalczukm answer, a quartz filter can solve this.  I had created my own and shared it on Github.  You can install it easily with a single command line.  It doesn't install any software, just the quartz filter only.

https://github.com/superman-lopez/compressjpeginpreview

#### Install

Run below code in your terminal:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Filters/ && curl -o ~/Library/Filters/Compress\ Images\ in\ PDF.qfilter https://raw.githubusercontent.com/superman-lopez/compressjpeginpreview/master/Compress%20Images%20in%20PDF.qfilter
```

#### Usage

After this the filter can be used in Preview.app (and other apps that support quartz filters).

1. Open the PDF in Preview.app
2. Select *File* and *Export...*
3. Choose *Format* to be *PDF*
4. Choose *Quartz Filter* to *Compress Images in PDF*
5. Choose your prefered destination and click *Save*

Comment: This works pretty well, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this website: https://smallpdf.com/compress-pdf to shrink PDFs to a really small size. The PDF quality is still really good even after the compression.

Comment: Nice platform, but unfortunately timed out for me 4k page PDF (3+ GB) 
> "Compressing your PDF File took too long. Maximum compression time is currently limited to 10 Minutes."

Comment: I've used that briefly so far in trial mode. Bulk-compresses PDFs in Finder from service menu, save a lot of space (in pro mode). Quite convenient! Prices are [$11.60/month or $105/year](https://smallpdf.com/pro).

Answer (score 2):

This is for anyone who is in the same boat as I was. I had a PDF of handwritten annotations on a book exported from Goodnotes. The Quartz Filter method didn't work for me, even when I applied a custom filter with aggressive settings. This makes me think that the filter is only applied to images in the PDF. In my case, the most aggressive filter reduced a PDF of size 104 MB to 103 MB!

### Using Automator to Reduce PDF Size

**Note**: This method works by converting pages in your PDF to compressed JPEGs and then stitching them back into a PDF, so other PDF data such as bookmarks and notes will be stripped.

- Open Automator.
- Go to **File** > **New** and Choose **Workflow**.
- Create the Workflow as follows.

  - In the left pane, look for **Ask for Finder Items** and drag it to the right pane.
  - Next, add **Render PDF Pages as Images** and set the Compression and Resolution of the JPEGs.
  - Finally, add **New PDF from Images**.
- Click on **Run** (top-right), choose your PDF and wait for Automator to do its job.

In my case, this reduced the file size to 10 MB.

Here's a screenshot of my Workflow:

[image: Workflow Screenshot]

This answer is based on [this answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3311405?answerId=17267270022#17267270022) on Apple communities.

Comment: Doesn’t this decrease quality of the PDF?

Comment: The JPEG compression level and Resolution can be set. It's not lossless but that's true for the Quartz Filter method too.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is not bothered by losing a bit of quality and if it is a single page document

These are the steps

1. open the large size pdf, File -> Export -> Format (change to JPEG-2000) -> Quality (change to lossless) -> Resolution (change to 200 pixels/inch) -> Save
2. Now open the JPEG and export it as PDF.

For my file it reduced from 4MB to 700KB with negligible loss of quality.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a pdf which is version 1.6 or 1.7, you can use the duplicate setting in  Preview. Preview will save the file as a 1.4 pdf and save about 50% in file size. As far as I can tell there is no loss of quality. No need to use the export - reduced file size unless you want further savings.

Comment: That might work, OK, for some documents intended for print. But the reasoning is doubtful. Usually increasing PDF version allows for better compression etc. Do you realise that using Preview in this way is lossy, e.g. re: document structure: you'll loose bookmarks for example?

Comment: I'm just describing some findings from working with Preview and PDFs.  I don't understand why this works the way it does but that's what I learned..

Comment: Well i cant get this to repeat with a newer version of preview.  i don;t know what happened.  I'm sure my earlier analysis was correct.

Comment: I'm confident your *observation* was correct (the "explanation" likely not). That's why this A is still OK & the method worth a shot. There are quite a few *very awful* PDFs out there. Even from really big publishers. (Have you tried with the same PDFs but with newer Preview?) Since the PDF-spec itself is a mess: Apart from ensuring to control creation from the start, the "best" method has to be tried out, almost each time…