# How to get my Mac (High Sierra) to recognize custom Quartz filters I created to reduce file size?

Tags: pdf, preview, filesystem

I want to create custom Quartz filters to reduce file sizes to custom specifications when exporting a PDF in Preview.

I found a helpful [article](https://www.macworld.com/article/1168311/software/shrink-preview-files-without-ruining-image-quality.html) on how to do it with an old operating system.

I found the code to modify here on Ask Different: [How to decrease .pdf size without losing quality](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297417/how-to-decrease-pdf-size-without-losing-quality?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

My only problem is I can't get my Mac to recognize and use the custom files I created. It looks like the file structure has changed as Mac has upgraded its operating system. I have tried placing the files in the following locations and none of them have worked.

```
Library/Filters/ (created a new Filters folder)

Library/Users/my_user_name/Library/Filters/ (created a new Filters folder)

Library/PDF Services/

Library/PDF Services/Filters/ (created a new Filters folder)

System/Library/Filters (not allowed to edit)
```

This was my reference, [macrumors.com](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-happened-to-system-library-filters.1938738/), for where to place the files.

I am running High Sierra 10.13.4.

Answer (score 3):

I have had success on macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 with putting Quartz filters in a `Filters` folder within my user's `Library` folder:

`/Users/my_user_name/Library/Filters/`

in other words:

`Macintosh HD > Users > my_user_name > Library > Filters`

However, your `Library` folder is normally hidden. An easy way to navigate to it is to click on the Go menu in Finder and while the menu is down hold the Option key. `Library` will then appear in the list. Once you open it you can create the `Filters` folder which probably doesn't exist, and put your filters there.

For reference, the filters I am using are those that [Josh Carr posted to GitHub](https://github.com/joshcarr/Apple-Quartz-Filters).

Comment: I used parameters from https://blog.online-convert.com/compress-pdfs-on-macos-without-losing-quality/
Med - qual = 0.5, Max Size 1684
High - qual = 0.75, Max Size 3508

Answer (score 1):

If the Quartz Filter is not correctly written (it's an XML file), then it will not load. 
The ColorSync Utility should show you all the installed Filters on the system. You can also create and edit them here.

As you say, Filters will be loaded from any "Filters" subfolder of the User or root-level Library. (Also the /System/Library/Filters folder, now protected by SIP.) This has not changed in any version of MacOS.

Filters can be placed in the PDF Services subfolder of the Libraries, and then will appear in the PDF button of the print menu. If selected, a PDF will be saved to the Desktop with the Filter applied.

There was a bug in early versions of High Sierra in which filters would not always be applied to certain PDFs, but it has been fixed by Mojave, if not earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In Catalina (and probably earlier) you can also use the ColorSyncUtility that comes with MacOS and add new filters under "Filters".

If you just want to adjust an existing filter, right click on the filter you want to change and select duplicate. Now you can change the values as you wish. You also have the option to create a whole bunch of new filters.