# Reduce file size of pdf text file scanned with app

Tags: mac, pdf

I had scanned 11 sites of a document in black and white and exports it as an pdf file. With two different known apps I got a file size of about 8MB. I tried different solutions with ColorSync filter or ghostScript commands but the pdf size does not shrink noticeable.

With scans from a printer I got pdf files with about 10 percent of that size without loss of quality. Does anyone knows how to reduce a large pdf file?

Comment: How did the app scan the document?  Was it an image or was it text?  Same question for the ptinter?

Comment: What DPI are your documents?

Comment: 11 pages of pdf at 8MB is **tiny** already. What are you hoping to gain?

Comment: I scanned the same document later with my printer and got a file size of 1MB for b/w and 300dpi. I looked into the file from the app and see that the first page was an image with RGB 8 pits per component and a size of 3555x2522 for an a4 page. With the app I could only set up black and white but this seams not to work very well. The document ist only text.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297417/how-to-decrease-pdf-size-without-losing-quality/

Answer (score -1):

You can use sites like Compress FDF (https://smallpdf.com/compress-pdf), PDF Compressor (https://pdfcompressor.com/), or Compress PDF online (https://www.ilovepdf.com/compress_pdf). Remember, google is always there for you.